# Is "hear our king teaches me" grammatically correct?

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

> I would like to hear our king teaches me.

Is that correct? Should I use *teach* instead of the 3rd person singular as it has a modal verb, or must *teach* be in a conditional sentence that requires the simple past?

I was trying to make a plain opinion or it have to be infinitive *to teach* or gerund *teaching*. Could someone please explain to me the whole rule?

Comment: Infinitive (without the "to" marker: **_I would like to hear our king teach me._** Gerund: **_I would like to hear our king teaching me._**

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, but it still confuses me why can't it be a third person singular verb, what makes that so, what is the rule?.

Comment: I'm not sure what rule you are looking for. "I would like to hear our king teaches me" is not grammatical in English. The verb _hear_ takes a noun phrase as its object, and "our king teaches me" is not a NP but a complete sentence.

Comment: I mean, the sentence explains that I would like to hear (the king teaches me), as it a verb of the king teaching me and King is a singular pronoun, why can't it have a singular verb, what is the rule of that, why it is grammatical incorrect to put a third singular verb that is basically used for singular pronoun.

Comment: _Hear_ (and other verbs of its type) takes an _object_ (our king) and a _bare infinitive_ (teach) or a _gerund_ (teaching). The verb _teach_ does not have _our king_ as its subject. _Our king_ is the object of _hear,_ not the _subject_ of _teach._ See [**this link**](http://www.grammaring.com/see-watch-hear-listen-feel-smell-notice-observe-object-bare-infinitive) for example.

Comment: Oh alright thanks , I didn't know that after the verbs of perception it should be a bare infinitive, that's the rule I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following verbs of perception (hear, see, etc.) you may use either the infinitive form or the gerund form.  The grammar and meaning are different for each.

In your example the infinitive is *teach* or *to teach*.  So the correct grammar is:

> I would like to hear our king *teach* me.

Alternately, if you want to express an ongoing action, use the gerund:

> I would like to hear our king *teaching* me.

Now ... while this is correct grammar this is not natural English. For starters, *hear* is passive while *listen* is active.  If the king were teaching you, you would probably pay attention, so the more appropriate verb would be to *listen*.

But again, it's odd to say you would only *listen* to someone teach you something.  Usually we would *get* (or be *given*) a lesson, or *attend* a lesson, or at the very least (if we were not part of the class) *observe* a lesson.  We would get the full experience, not just the auditory part.  So if you are the one being taught by the king, you would use a more comprehensive verb to describe the experience, and not just "hear":

> I would like to *have* our king teach me.

Since this is an odd example, here are some others:

> I would like to listen to him play Beethoven.
>
> I would like to listen to him playing Beethoven.

.

> I would like to watch her cook us dinner.
>
> I would like to watch her cooking us dinner.

.

> I love to hear the birds sing
>
> I love to hear the birds singing

[More on verbs of perception](http://www.grammaring.com/see-watch-hear-listen-feel-smell-notice-observe-object-bare-infinitive)

Comment: What does "_hear_ is passive" mean? _"They heard our voices"_ certainly seems active to me.

Comment: @P.E.Dant he's saying that the act of "hearing" is passive (involuntary)  compared to  "listening", which is usually said to be volitive/active.

Comment: @Mari-LouA There is no difference at all between the acts of hearing and listening. _Hearing_ may _very_ subtly imply understanding words, as opposed to merely letting their sounds vibrate your eardrums, but it's a distinction without a difference. Our eardrums can't somehow reach out and "actively" gather those sounds. _To hear_ is every bit as "active" as _to listen._ **Hear** is not a "passive" verb, whatever that means.

Comment: @P.E.Dant i was explaining why Andrew chose the expression "passive", your comment seemed to suggest that the passive form was being used. My comment was really there to clarify the meaning of "passive" = *involuntary*, more than anything else. We speak about "passive smoke" don't we?  What does that mean?

Comment: @Mari-LouA I know, and it's important that the OP not gather from the answer that there is something "passive" about hearing as opposed to listening. I can't understand what he's on about there, but it's not a good lesson for a learner.

Comment: @P.E.Dant  Well, Andrew argues that the verb *listen* fits better, and explains why. It seems pretty straightforward to me.

Comment: I guess _listen_ is a fine verb, but it's no more "active" than _hear._ We can't just invent new categories of "active" and "passive" verbs on a whim to suit our answer. The question is about the verbs of perception, and the answer is fine as far as that goes. Creating a new "passive verb" category, though, is right out.

Comment: Andrew hasn't invented anything, the fact that hearing is called [a "passive" activity](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/12883/44619) compared to that of listening is nothing fandangled. [*To hear is the passive thing that happens automatically.*](http://www.duotesting.com/en/english-articles/listen-vs-hear)

Comment: @Mari-LouA The answer is fine when it sticks to the subject.  I don't intend to get into a prolonged colloquy on this point, but whoever "duotesting.com" is, there is nothing there to convince anyone of their "authority". Their own invention of these new categories of verbs is no more convincing than that in this answer. I could easily create a website which proposes that some verbs are "whimsical" and others are "non-whimsical". This would not be useful as the basis for an answer to a new learner of English. There is no such thing as a "passive" or "active" verb, except in terms of voice.

Comment: We are talking about "meaning"; **passive** [*3. Existing, conducted, or experienced without active or concerted effort*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/passive)

Comment: @Mari-LouA You believe that hearing is _"experienced without active or concerted effort,_" while listening is not, correct? To those who give credence to this belief, then, the act of "listening" is voluntary, while the act of "hearing" is not. Therefore, it must be possible for a person (importantly, _without_ introducing a barrier to prevent sound waves from vibrating the eardrums) to cease "listening". This supposition is based upon an extraordinary notion, it seems to me. What does the "non-listener" do? Does she refuse to process the sounds in _Wernicke's area_ of the brain?

Comment: @P.E.Dante Take it up with Andrew, it's his post not mine. I just explained its meaning and gave supporting evidence.